# Google App Invite - Theme change

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play-services, google-app-invites

Is it possible to set the app invite activity that shows the list of users/friends to use the app's current theme? Right now its a bit different from mine and for the sake of continuity I'd like it to be the same.

Comment: Checked with official doc and didn't find anything. This feature might be added in the future.

Comment: Thanks @bjiang I figure that they'll add it soon I was just wondering if it's already there and I just missed it.

Answer (score 1):

Checked with official doc and didn't find anything. This feature might be added in the future.